# Image Margins in CKEditor

Tags: css, image, ckeditor

The Image properties dialog has `HSpace` and `VSpace` settings. When I go to the advanced tab, I can see that it's actually setting the margin styles. I want to be able to set each margin individually. For example, a right-aligned image would have a left and bottom margin, but not top or right. Is there a way to allow for setting each of the four margins individually?

Comment: Using CSS in preferred over inline styles. You can create your own styles and apply them to your image using CK's stylesheets.

Comment: @Diodeus - I agree with you on principle, but in my case I need to edit each value individually in a user-friendly manner.

Comment: In your case you'd need to create a plug-in that would allow for the editing of margin/top/bottom/left/right. hspace and vspace cannot do what you need.

Comment: Re-create the entire Image Properties dialog? That's a rather daunting project for such a small change.

Comment: It is what it is. There is no easy way.

Comment: @Diodeus - If you add your comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS in preferred over inline styles. You can create your own styles and apply them to your image using CK's stylesheets. Note that CK has a separate stylehsheet for the editor itself as well as one for the contents of the editor pane.